# How to handle nested documents with Searchkick and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have `equity_contracts` table which has one `user_contract` and many `prices`. `EquityContract` model looks like:

```
class EquityContract < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :ticker, :name, :country, :currency

  has_one :user_contract, as: :contract
  has_many :prices

  searchkick

  scope :search_import, -> { includes(:user_contract, :prices) }

  def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      ticker: ticker,
      country: country,
      user_id: user_contract.try(:user_id),
      prices: prices.map do |price|
        {
          traded_on: price.traded_on.to_s,
          close: price.close
        }
      end
    }
  end
end
```

`UserContract` which looks like:

```
class UserContract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contract, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now I want to index the keys (`name`, `ticker` ,`country`,`user_id` ,`prices`) in `EquityContract` so I run `EquityContract.reindex`.

Now when I try to do something like `equity = EquityContract.search "APPL_US"` I get `Searchkick::Results` object which looks something like:

```
[24] pry(main)> equity = EquityContract.search "APPL_US", limit: 1
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url=http://127.0.0.1:9200/equity_contracts_development/_search response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.101687
  EquityContract Search (109.5ms)  curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/equity_contracts_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"APPL_US","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"APPL_US","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"APPL_US","operator":"and","boost":1,"analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"APPL_US","operator":"and","boost":1,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3}}}]}},"size":1,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
=> #<Searchkick::Results:0x0000036f6915a0
 @klass=
  EquityContract(id: integer, ticker: text, name: string, country: string, currency: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime),
 @options=
  {:page=>1,
   :per_page=>1,
   :padding=>0,
   :load=>true,
   :includes=>nil,
   :json=>false,
   :match_suffix=>"analyzed",
   :highlighted_fields=>[]},
 @response=
  {"took"=>99,
   "timed_out"=>false,
   "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0},
   "hits"=>
    {"total"=>3,
     "max_score"=>0.005845671,
     "hits"=>
      [{"_index"=>"equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
        "_type"=>"equity_contract",
        "_id"=>"234",
        "_score"=>0.005845671}]}}>
```

The main issue here that I would like to see the index results as I made earlier and to see results for fields (`name`, `ticker` ,`country`,`user_id` ,`prices`).

When I try to access ElasticSearch through the RESTful API:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/equity_contracts_development/_search\?pretty -d '{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":[{"not":{"filter":{"missing":{"field":"user_id","existence":true,"null_value":true}}}}]}}},"size":100,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
```

I get a result like:

```
{
  "took" : 54,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 207,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "64",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "83",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "90",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "127",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "139",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "590",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "608",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "622",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "658",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "665",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "equity_contracts_development_20160317185615341",
      "_type" : "equity_contract",
      "_id" : "672",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }]
  }
}
```

How can I see results for associated mapped objects like in `prices`? At the moment `equity.results` returns arrays of activerecord object `EquityContract` and not the indexed attributes.

I wanna return attributes specified in `EquityContract#search_data`and tried `equity.response['hits']['hits']` bit it doesn't include the needed attributes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I had to add `load: false` to `#search` something like:

```
equity = EquityContract.search "APPL_US", limit: 1, load: false
```

Then I'll get `_source` with the response which includes the attributes. You can add `source=true` to the HTTP request and you should get a full attributes with the response.